# Difficulty posting Actions to Timeline

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I've tried building the basis of our next app following [Facebook's Open Graph Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/) but for some reason I'm getting errors thrown at me regardless of how I try POSTing an action.

I'll go as in-depth as I can here as I hope it'll be very useful for all developers getting to grips with the new Timeline.

I've defined a **battle** action and a **hero** object using the default settings when setting up each. **transcendgame** is my namespace.

`$id` is the userid of the Facebook user (I've tried using /me/, the direct id has always been less problematic in the past for me).

`$herourl` is an urlencoded string pointing to a separate webpage with the following content:

```html
 <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# transcendgame: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/transcendgame#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id"      content="[my id]"> 
  <meta property="og:type"        content="transcendgame:hero"> 
  <meta property="og:url"         content="http://apps.facebook.com/transcendgame/"> 
  <meta property="og:title"       content="Hercules"> 
  <meta property="og:description" content="As this game is still in development, you can ignore this feed post!"> 
  <meta property="og:image"       content="[an image url]">
```

The application canvas page contains the following code. It should POST a new action event to the user's timeline, but is consistently giving me "Error occured". I have also tried it with the sample hero object (samples.ogp.me...) with the same problem.

```
<script>
    function doTest()
        {
            FB.api('/<?=$id?>/transcendgame:battle' + 
                        '?hero=<?=$herourl?>','post',
                        function(response) {
                if (!response || response.error) {
                        alert('Error occured');
                } else {
                    alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
                    }
            });
        }
    </script>

    <a href="#" onclick="doTest(); return false">Test fb post</a>
```

I'm calling the JS SDK and running fb.init correctly. I honestly don't know where the problem even lies, let alone how to fix it.

**EDIT:** I've correctly added the user's access token to the API call:

```
FB.api('/me/transcendgame:battle' + 
                    '?hero=<?=$herourl?>&access=<?=$token?>','post',
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Type: OAuthException

Message: (#3502) Object at URL [url] has og:type of 'game'. The property 'hero' requires an object of og:type 'transcendgame:hero'.
```

This is odd, as the webpage definitely does have og:type set correctly, as listed earlier in this question. Is this some Facebook hiccup I need to work around?

**SECOND EDIT**: Fixed the final problem.

The **og:url** I had assumed to point back to the URL of the app's canvas, but it needs to reference *itself* instead. For instance, if your object is on mydomain.com/object1.php then the code must be:

```
<meta property="og:url"         content="http://www.mydomain.com/object1.php">
```

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem and I changed the callback to be more helpful:

```
  var fb_url = '/me/YOUR_NAMESPACE?key=value';
  FB.api(fb_url,'post',
    function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      if (!response || response.error) {
        var msg = 'Error occured';
        if (response.error) {
          msg += "\n\nType: "+response.error.type+"\n\nMessage: "+response.error.message;
        }
        alert(msg);
      } else {
        alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
      }
    }
  );
```

UPDATE

I finally got a post to the timeline, and the change I had to make was to use the BETA version of JavaScript SDK.  ( https://developers.facebook.com/support/beta-tier/ )

Use this:

```
<script src="//connect.beta.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=xxx&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
```

Instead of this:

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=xxx&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
```

Comment: Wish the beta version fixed it for me too! I appreciate the extended JS snippet you used, I'm diehard PHP but clueless about JS. Grabbing and appending an access token fixed that problem, but now I'm having another one which doesn't make much sense. I'll edit my original question to detail it.

Comment: I have og:url set to URL of page itself, so try that just to see if it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

i had some difficultly posting initially as well.
My problem lied the configuration settings of the action.
Make sure that your actions are set to be for the exact object.
Here are some screens of what I have set up and working:

[image]
[image]

If these settings are correct, check the error code that comes back from facebook, post it here and i can help you further.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the final point on og:url -- that's correct.  You can generally consider the OG URL to be the "primary key" of an Object in the Graph.

Answer (score 0):

To clear up some possible confusion, the `og:url` doesn't "`HAVE`" to be the same `URL` as the `url` of your `object1.php` page. The important thing to note is that regardless of the `URL` that you reference there, it has to have the `META` tags in the `html &lt;head&gt;` of the page.

I, for example, put the `URL` of a canvas page in there so that when someone clicks the hyperlink in the action on the timeline it opens that page. As long as the `META` information from the `'Get Code'` link for the Object is in the head, you won't get the error.