# Timeline posting from wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

Recommendation Bar requires 
and add to timeline opengraph tag requires

Why they haven't fixed it yet? That bar is what controls the "Read" action to be posted. Or anyone has other idea how to override this?

I get an error of

"The Open Graph object has the wrong type for the given property"

but I tried both with article and namespace:article. The Debugger is perfect. no warnings or errors.

I always tried using the beta js call as mentioned here [Difficulty posting Actions to Timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570335/difficulty-posting-actions-to-timeline)

Do we just wait for October 29th when its officially out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is/was a bug with the debugger related to timeline and open graph. Be sure to search thru facebook bugs here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Yeah, sorry, its known bug and I joined the subcribed. thank you!